# Reported ember version does not match bower.json

Tags: ember.js, dependencies, version

At some point we upgraded from Ember 1.13 to 2.2, are using 2.2 features, and our `bower.json` has

```
{
  "name": "<our project name>",
  "dependencies": {
     "ember": "2.2.0",
     .
     .
  }
}
```

But `ember --version` output is still

```
version: 1.13.13
.
.
```

What's going on?

Comment: To know the correct version of emberjs in use, use Ember inspector.

Answer (score 2):

`ember --version` returns ember-cli version. This one could differ from ember.js version.

`ember help` returns man page:

```
ember version <options...>
  outputs ember-cli version
  aliases: v, --version, -v
  --verbose (Boolean) (Default: false)
```

In general using same versions of ember-cli and ember.js is good practice.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You´re propably using Ember-Cli, the version shown is from ember-cli in the package.json